# rescue_from ::AbstractController::ActionNotFound not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, exception, ruby-on-rails-3.2, actioncontroller

I have the following code:

```
unless Rails.application.config.consider_all_requests_local
  rescue_from Exception, with: :render_exception
  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, with: :render_exception
  rescue_from ActionController::UnknownController, with: :render_exception
  rescue_from ::AbstractController::ActionNotFound, with: :render_exception
  rescue_from ActiveRecord::ActiveRecordError, with: :render_exception
  rescue_from NoMethodError, with: :render_exception
end
```

They all work flawless, except ::AbstractController::ActionNotFound

I've also tried

```
AbstractController::ActionNotFound
ActionController::UnknownAction
```

error:

```
   AbstractController::ActionNotFound (The action 'show' could not be found for ProductsController):
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[This similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7342851/catch-unknown-action-in-rails-3-for-custom-404) suggests that you can no longer catch an `ActionNotFound` exception. Check the link for workarounds. [This suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7344312/760389) to use a Rack middleware to catch 404s looks the cleanest to me.

Answer (score 3):

To rescue `AbstractController::ActionNotFound` in a controller, you can try something like this:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  private

  def process(action, *args)
    super
  rescue AbstractController::ActionNotFound
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render :404, status: :not_found }
      format.all { render nothing: true, status: :not_found }
    end
  end


  public

  # actions must not be private

end
```

This overrides the `process` method of `AbstractController::Base` that raises `AbstractController::ActionNotFound` (see [source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.2.21/actionpack/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb#L104-L122)).

Answer (score 0):

I think we should catch `AbstractController::ActionNotFound` in `ApplicationController`. I have tried following that **does not appears to be working**.

```
rescue_from ActionController::ActionNotFound, with: :action_not_found
```

I have found much cleaner way to handle this exception in `ApplicationController`. To handle the `ActionNotFound` Exception in your application, you have to override the `action_missing` method in your application controller.

```
def action_missing(m, *args, &block)
  Rails.logger.error(m)
  redirect_to not_found_path # update your application 404 path here
end
```

Solution Adapted from: [coderwall handling exceptions in your rails application](https://coderwall.com/p/whjmra/handling-exceptions-in-your-rails-application)

Answer (score 0):

Overriding `process`, as described by Grégoire in his answer, seems to work. However, the Rails code says to instead override `process_action`. That doesn't work, though, because `process_action` never gets called due to the check for action_name in `process`.

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.2.21/actionpack/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb#L115

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.2.21/actionpack/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb#L161